# Check if entry exists with mySQL / PHP without getting timeout?

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded on the line here that checks if a mySQL entry exists. Even when I set a large max execution time it will have this error!

```
function checkReleasePosted($releaseID){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `releases` WHERE `releaseID` = '$releaseID' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){
        return 'Assigned';
    } else {
        return 'Available';
    }
};
```

Does anyone know of another way I can check the entry to avoid this error? (I am just learning with the old API and will change it to mysqli soon!). Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days. Many thanks

Comment: PHP functions that start with `mysql_` have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

Comment: thanks, yes I will do soon

Comment: Is your `releases` table data too large? Cause it's a simple `SELECT` query, doesn't have to take this long.

Comment: Do you have PHPMyAdmin or command line access to the db server? Can you try executing a hard-coded query and see what happens? For example: ``SELECT * FROM `releases` WHERE `releaseID` = '1' LIMIT 1``.

Comment: If its taking that long to execute the query, you are probably running on a large table without indexes or without using indexes.

Comment: hi the table is empty at first

Comment: and remains tiny so that isn't the problem, thanks though!

Comment: thanks! yes it was a number but I just did this and I'm still getting the error unfortunately, is there anything else it could be?

Comment: it happens even with a few entries still..

Comment: Is php and mysql on the same machine, or across a network? Can you ping the mysql box to make sure the connection is not a problem?

Comment: Hi it is on a web server and other queries are fine.. maybe the source id could be getting lost somewhere. The query works fine in phpMyAdmin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are possibly comparing a numeric column (`releaseID`) with a string value (`'$releaseID'`). This kills the index. Remove those quotes, if `$releaseID` is in fact a number and not a string.

Comment: thanks! yes it was a number but I just did this and I'm still getting the error unfortunately, is there anything else it could be?

Answer (score 0):

This will make it easier

```
function checkReleasePosted($releaseID){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `releases` WHERE `releaseID` = $releaseID LIMIT 1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows>0){
    return 'Assigned';
} else {
    return 'Available';
}
};
```